# Try to use bs4 get some infos from wikipedia

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I started to learn python this year as the new year resolutions;P I encountered some problems when self-learning web-scraping. This may be a dumb questions but I hope someone can point out problems of my codes. 
Thanks in advance!

I want to web-scraping from Wikipedia Nobel Economic Prize https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_Memorial_Prize_laureates_in_Economics

```
# I first get the whole table
wiki_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable'})    

print(wiki_table)
# And grab the td information
name_list = wiki_table('td') 
print(name_list) 
type(name_list) #bs4.element.ResultSet
type(name_list[0:]) # list

# My goal is to separate laureate's name from other descriptions i.e. countries, years...What I plan to do is first get some lists containing people's names and then clean others unwanted strings. 
# I tried to loop both the bs4 type and list type 

laurates=[]
for a in name_list:
    laurates.append(name_list.find_all(class='a'))
print(laurates)

# I looped for a here because the html is like `<a href="/wiki/Ragnar_Frisch" title="Ragnar Frisch">Ragnar Frisch</a>`. I thought the name is with the a code (or I interpreted wrongly?)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way(in this case) is just to load the table into a pandas dataframe and then extract from that whatever items you need using the usual pandas methods. So

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_Memorial_Prize_laureates_in_Economics"

pd.read_html(url)
```

will output the table on that page.